What would the Parametric Equations be to for Spiral that also follows the shape of a parabola?
I am using a spiral to create a model for the filament inside a incandescent light bulb. Currently I have the parametric equations, {x = 2t, y = cos(10t), z = sin(10t)} for 0 < t < 10 but I need the graph to follow the shape of a parabola (x^2) while maintaining the coil/spiral shape.
Bending Spring
Sine Curve mapped onto parabola

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to Math.SE! ... The helix
$$(x,y,z)=\left(;t \cos(k t),;t \sin(k t),;a t^2;\right)$$
follows the parabolic surface $z = a ( x^2+y^2 )$. Does that help?

In your solution the diameter of the spiral is ever changing and thus the graph looks similar to a tornado. I am trying to keep the diameter and properties of the spiral/coil while mapping into to follow the shape of a parabola, which looks similar to bending a spring (See Images).

I'd do it in stages. Like this: https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxVj8FuwjAQRO%5F7FVM4kASTOm5RufjUMxJC3BBFxgSwmtjBWWg%5Fv3KQkHraHc1o9u0YKxPNITTOwgbXlFgtodbOn6Gkei%5FlolSK7iZmE57kRAYasvygOMyK%5FA0alSIa%5FyuKNV2hca8th5htWcCgAH8pAbnLU3pj%5FLn2TC00VDG4ZFMXXtFfI2cVpmi%5FVE49NFoUsDTGOrBhFzxaw9H90jJ5w5ptCdhagVmfboikegH7FFJAClQ7QQ%2DAz%2DAaOH4hvgwInUMBfxtAOmhcMcUSxfMHKRATRegzvuQP0TufRCpcQaMz0bQ1R2f3XRP47Zh1AhkLzKpyLlCV8zyh2NCEqEfj02ExEkjJfRec514rKWVOq7K%5FhJ%5FslMr0Jt5qAb7Uba0nRxO%5FJwLBN84%5FrJz%2DALLAeeY=&lang=sage
